# Is there possible ways to print a returning stack from a fuction?

Tags: c++, recursion

I try to use stack function to convert decimal number to binary number and return the stack function value to main function but I am not able to output the correct result to the screen.(sorry for my English)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
stack<int> BinaryNum(int k, stack<int> st){
    if(k >= 1){
        st.push(k % 2);
        return BinaryNum(k / 2, st);
    }
    if(k < 1)
        return st;
}
int main(){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    stack<int> st;
    BinaryNum(k,st);
    while(!st.empty()){
        cout << st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the correct result and what input are you giving this? I recommend hardcoding a test case rather than using `cin`, because that's not reproducible. Thanks.

Comment: what is 'Recursion'

Comment: The posted code does not compile:  `temp.cpp:7:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Recursion'`

Comment: missing assignment so IMO typo.

Comment: @MarekR and/or missing reference parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You discard the result of `BinaryNum` in `main`, and are passing *copies* of your stack around.

Either use the result

```
int main(){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    stack<int> st;
    st = BinaryNum(k,st);
    while(!st.empty()){
        cout << st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
}
```

or take `st` by reference in `BinaryNum`

```
stack<int> BinaryNum(int k, stack<int> & st){
    if(k >= 1){
        st.push(k % 2);
        return BinaryNum(k / 2, st);
    }
    if(k < 1)
        return st;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to store the return value of your function in the variable `st`. Just change the line

```
BinaryNum(k,st);
```

to

```
st = BinaryNum(k,st);
```

and it will work.